# Bash: Elegant way to run a command and exit if a process exited with error

Tags: bash, operators, exit, logical-operators

I have a this logic in a Bash script:

Run something;
If it failed, print something and stop;
If not, run something else.
And all this runs in a `ssh` session.

This is probably trivial if I used `$?` and `if / else`.
But because of the script maintainability, I am looking for some elegant 2 lines solution.

This is what I have so far

```
ssh ... '
ls attributes/*'$CONF_FILE'.rb || ls -l attributes/ && exit 1;
'$EDITOR' attributes/*'$CONF_FILE'.rb '$PART_VER';'
```

However, this exits no matter what. So I tried:

```
ssh ... '
ls attributes/*'$CONF_FILE'.rb || (ls -l attributes/ && exit 1);
'$EDITOR' attributes/*'$CONF_FILE'.rb '$PART_VER';'
```

However, `exit` only exits the subshell. And [exiting a script from within a subshell is not elegant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48533/exit-shell-script-from-a-subshell) at all.

Is there a simple 2-lines solution? Perhaps other operators precedence?

Comment: Terseness and maintainability are **opposing** forces in shell. Terse code is likely to sacrifice correctness for that terseness, and thus to have more hidden bugs. Approaches following best practices to be obviously correct (to folks relevant with the pertinent best-practice idioms, of course) are not terse.

Comment: Are you running `ls` simply to see if the config file already exists? There are better ways to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Written for clarity, correctness, and maintainability -- **not** terseness:

```
# store your remote script as a string. Because of the quoted heredoc, no variables are
# evaluated at this time; $1, $2 and $3 are expanded only after the code is sent to the
# remote system.
script_text=$(cat <<'EOF'
  CONF_FILE=$1; PART_VER=$2; EDITOR=$3
  shopt -s nullglob                   # Return an empty list for any failed glob
  set -- attributes/*"$CONF_FILE".rb  # Replace our argument list with a glob result
  if (( $# )); then                   # Check length of that result...
    "$EDITOR" "$@" "$PART_VER"        # ...if it's nonzero, run the editor w/ that list
  else
    ls attributes                     # otherwise, run ls and fail
    exit 1
  fi
EOF
)

# generate a single string to pass to the remote shell which passes the script text
# ...and the arguments to place in $0, $1, etc while that script is running
printf -v ssh_cmd_str '%q ' \
  bash -c "$script_text" '_' "$CONF_FILE" "$PART_VER" "$EDITOR"

# ...thereafter, that command can be run as follows:
ssh -tt ... "$ssh_cmd_str"
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, I resorted to duplicating the condition, like this:

```
ssh ... '
ls attributes/*'$CONF_FILE'.rb >  /dev/null || ls -l --color=always attributes/
ls attributes/*'$CONF_FILE'.rb >  /dev/null || exit 1;
'$EDITOR' attributes/*'$CONF_FILE'.rb '$PART_VER';'
```

(I used `&>-` as a short for redirecting stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`, but that is not probably correct, see the comment.)

Comment: `&>-` closes a FD, it does not direct it to `/dev/null`. All writes to that FD thus always fail. You can test yourself that `echo >&-` has an exit status of 1, whereas `echo >/dev/null` succeeds.

Comment: Interesting, so that middle line will always exit? For some reason currently this way does what it should...

Comment: Maybe you're running on a platform where `ls` doesn't treat a failed write as worthy of a nonzero exit status? Not something that can be trusted to behave reliably across platforms, though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a subshell; use a command group.

```
ssh ... "
  ls attributes/*'$CONF_FILE'.rb || { ls -l attributes/ && exit 1; };
  '$EDITOR' attributes/*'$CONF_FILE'.rb '$PART_VER';"
```

(Note the change in quotes; this better ensures that the result of the local parameter expansions are properly quoted on the remote end, although there will still be problems if the parameter expansions themselves contain single quotes. A proper solution would run an explicit shell on the remote end, taking your local parameters as arguments, instead of using interpolation to build the script. The following is untested, but I think I quoted everything correctly.

```
ssh ... sh -c '
          ls attributes/*"$1.rb" || { ls -l attributes/ && exit 1; };
          "$EDITOR" attributes/*"\$1.rb" "$2";
        ' _ "$CONF_FILE" "$PART_VER"
```

)